# Remote Desktop do not work when changed USB network adapter. Error code 0x4

Tags: remote-desktop

I have used Remote Desktop from my Mac to my Windows computer and when I changed the USB network adapter from a TP-link to another TP-link that is more “powerful” it didn't work with the new one.

It works with the old but not with the new (Archer T9UH). With the new I get the error code: 0x4.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2wCx.png)

Is there anybody that has an idea what the problem with the new one might be?

I have tried to see if there are some changes in the settings between the two adapters but can’t see if there is a difference. I have check that Remote Desktop is ok in the “Allow apps to communicate through Windows Defender Firewall”

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by going in to my TP link setting. Under Advanced -> NAT Forwarding -> Port Forwarding I looked up what my Device IP Adress was. In the internet Protocol Version 4 ( TCP/IPv4) in properties for the Wifi 2 properties in Network Connections in the control panel. I changed to my Device IP Adress was in Ip address. Then it came up a warning that if I proceeded I would remove the settings from the other adapter. I pressed “ok” and it then worked.